# Proving triangle inequality for a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Q: Consider the mapping $||*||_1:\mathbb{C}^3 \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ given by
$||(z_1,z_2,z_3)||_1 = |z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|$. Show that $||*||_1$ is a norm on $\mathbb{C}^3$.

I have shown that the mapping satisfies homogeneity and positive-definiteness but I'm struggling with the triangle inequality part i.e. showing that $||u+v|| \le ||u|| + ||v||.$ This is what I have so far:

Let $z=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$, $z^{'}=(z_1^{'},z_2^{'},z_3^{'}) \in \mathbb{C}^3$.

$||(z+z^{'})||_1 = ||(z_1+z_1^{'},z_2+z_2^{'},z_3+z_3^{'})||$

$= |z_1+z_1^{'}|+|z_2+z_2^{'}|+|z_3+z_3^{'}|$

...and I'm stuck from there. I know I have to get to $||z+z^{'}||_1 \le ||z|| + ||z^{'}||$ but I'm not really sure how.

Am I approaching this in the right way? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Hint: you know the triangle inequality holds for the ordinary absolute value of complex numbers (or, if you don't, you should prove that). By the way, not that it matters so much here, but often the notation $z^*$ is reserved for the complex conjugate of a complex number; so you might want to use $z'_i$ or $w_i$ instead.

Comment: Edited original post, thanks for that heads up

Comment: Hint: $|z_i+z_i'|\leqslant |z_i|+|z_i'|$, and applying that for $i=1,2,3$ yields?

Comment: So this?

Let $z=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$, $z^{'}=(z_1^{'},z_2^{'},z_3^{'}) \in \mathbb{C}^3$.

$||(z+z^{'})||_1 = ||(z_1+z_1^{'},z_2+z_2^{'},z_3+z_3^{'})|= |z_1+z_1^{'}|+|z_2+z_2^{'}|+|z_3+z_3^{'}|$

Now since $|z_i+z_i'|\leqslant |z_i|+|z_i'|$, we have

$|z_1+z_1^{'}|+|z_2+z_2^{'}|+|z_3+z_3^{'}| \le |z_1|+|z_1^{'}|+|z_2|+|z_2^{'}|+|z_3|+|z_3^{'}|$

$\le (|z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|)+(|z_1^{'}|+|z_2^{'}|+|z_3^{'}|)$

$\le ||z||_1+||z'||_1$